# What does this line of code do?

Tags: c++, function

```
void expand_combinations(const char *remaining_string, string const & s, int rema
in_depth)
{
    if(remain_depth==0)
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    for(int k=0; k < strlen(remaining_string); ++k)
    {
        string str(s);
        str.append(1, remaining_string[k]);
        expand_combinations(remaining_string+k+1, str, remain_depth - 1); // what?
    }
    return;
}
```

On the call to the function, it's passing a string + an integer. What does that become?

Comment: It's called pointer arithmetic.  Perhaps you might benefit from [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I know about that stuff I just forgot since I've been using Objective-C lately.

Comment: Objective-C has pointer arithmetic, too, and it works exactly how you showed in both languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remaining_string is not a string; it's a pointer to a character. Therefore adding an integer to it simply moves the pointer.

For example, if `char *blah = "hello"`, then `blah+1` would point to `"ello"`.

Comment: remaining_string is not a pointer to a string; it's a pointer to a character.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: technically, yes, edited. Kind of nit-picking here, though, imho :) It is common to think of `char *` in C as pointers to "strings", even though obviously they technically point only to the first character.

Answer (score 3):

It's passing a pointer to the k+1th character. As it descends into the recursion, each call starts farther and farther into the string.